# Bad access exception in Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession when network connection is lost

Tags: poco-libraries

When I run the following code without a network connection, I get a bad access error on the last line.

```
Poco::URI uri(sRemoteLoggingURL);

HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, uri.getPathAndQuery());

request.set("User-Agent", "Poco");

string reqBody = "{\"logMessage\":\""+ message + "\", \"application_name\":\""+ sAppName +"\"}";
request.setContentLength( reqBody.length() );

std::ostream& sessionStream = session.sendRequest(request);
```

Is this expected behavior? Do I need to check for network connectivity before I try to send a request? If so, how do I do that? I've tried `session.connected()`, but that is returning false even when I do have a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Apparently, you need to be sure to call `reset` on the session before you destroy it (or before it goes out of scope) if there's an exception. This code works:

```
Poco::URI uri(sRemoteLoggingURL);

HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

try{

  HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, uri.getPathAndQuery());

  request.set("User-Agent", "Poco");

  string reqBody = "{\"logMessage\":\""+ message + "\", \"application_name\":\""+ sAppName +"\"}";
  request.setContentLength( reqBody.length() );

  std::ostream& sessionStream = session.sendRequest(request);


  if (sessionStream.good()) {

    sessionStream << reqBody;

    HTTPResponse res;

    string text;
    istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
    StreamCopier::copyToString(is, text);
  }

}catch(Poco::Exception& e){
  // apparently, you MUST call reset before destroying the session, or you'll crash
  session.reset();
  sdfLog::logFormat("appContent::doIdle Poco::Exception: %s\n", e.what());
}catch(...){
  session.reset();
  sdfLog::logFormat("appContent::doIdle exception in remote logger %s\n");
}
```